# JQuery UI not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to use JQuery UI but cant seem to get any of the methods working. 
I have been trying to show a dialog but havent been able to do it.
Jquery is workking.

I have used Firebug and i get no errors when loading the jqueryUi, Jquery files just 304 not modified status.

I dont know if im doing something stupid or i havent setup the JQuery UI right

Any help is appreciated

Heres the code that im using

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
if (jQuery.ui) {
alert("Success");
}
$("#dlg_hello").dialog();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dlg_hello">Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to capture the page load event to instantiate a jQuery UI object.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dlg_hello").dialog();
});
```

​

Comment: Check out the [short hand version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9586631/558021) too...

Answer (score 1):

Place your dialog in a document ready wrapper

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind your code to the document ready event, this way

```
$(function (){
    if (jQuery.ui) {
       alert("Success");
    }
    $("#dlg_hello").dialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function that jQuery provides to know when the framework has been loaded successfully and is ready to use -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    //  now we know that jQuery has been loaded and is ready.
  });
</script>
```